# Angular2 TS, single file upload is sending multiple files

Tags: node.js, file-upload, input, angular

I am using ng2-uploader, and when i upload the a file thefirst time it is fine i get this result:

```
POST /upload with {}
[ { fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'test.csv',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\Desktop\\Feedbacker\\server\\uploads',
    filename: 'hzct1ye7dr92bne9udi.csv',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\Desktop\\Feedbacker\\server\\uploads\\hzct1ye7dr92bne9udi.csv',
    size: 276 } ]
```

That is fine, as it is a single file upload. But then if i try to upload another file while on the same page, it decides to do two posts:

```
POST /upload with {}
POST /upload with {}
[ { fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'test.csv',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\Desktop\\Feedbacker\\server\\uploads',
    filename: 'tmyuvg88fsgfmn78ehfr.csv',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\Desktop\\Feedbacker\\server\\uploads\\tmyuvg88fsgfmn78ehfr.csv',
    size: 276 } ]
[ { fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'test - Copy.csv',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\Desktop\\Feedbacker\\server\\uploads',
    filename: '4psf329ig7g7quvm42t9.csv',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\Jezyk\\Desktop\\Feedbacker\\server\\uploads\\4psf329ig7g7quvm42t9.csv',
    size: 276 } ]
```

This is a problem as it is a single file upload and breaks any further handling of the files.

**Component**:

```
uploadFile: any;
options: Object = {
    url: '/api/upload',
};

handleUpload(data): void {
    if (data && data.response) {
        data = JSON.parse(data.response);
        this.uploadFile = data;
    }
}
```

This is my **html** for the file input:

```
<input type="file" accept=".csv" [ng-file-select]="options" (onUpload)="handleUpload($event)">
```

My **route**:

```
router.route('/upload').post(upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
});
```

Any reason why it is stacking the files ? As it shouldn't be reacting like this.

**EDIT:**
I have attempted this code, as i want to parse the csv file into jSON:

```
router.route('/upload').post(upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.json(req.files.map(file => {
        converter.fromFile(file.path ,function(err,result) {
            console.log(file.path);
        });
    }));
});
```

so i have logged the  `file.path` and on the second upload it messes up:

C:\Users\Jezyk\Desktop\Feedbacker\server\uploads\zlhui1y74tir1gbq33di.csv
C:\Users\Jezyk\Desktop\Feedbacker\server\uploads\qaz4e35vwjn9ffajor.csv

Is the result, it needs to only be one ... not sure why its keeping the previous data lol

Comment: I'm with the same problem, did you found a solution?